# unable to start program in visual studio 2019

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I have been using visual studio for my assignments for a programming class, and I received the error that says "unable to start program -- the system cannot find the file specified". I checked some of the solutions to this error and tried testing it out, but none of them solved it. Maybe I have a problem in my coding. This is the code (not finished yet):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define PI=3.1415
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

/**************************************************************************
     Function: display_myInfo()
     Input Paramaters: none
     Output data type: void
     Task: This function displays my name, email, and lab section to the screen in a box of star.
****************************************************************************/
void display_myInfo() {
    printf("\n**********************************");
    printf("\n*   CNIT 105 Assignment_5        *");
    printf("\n*  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx              *");
    printf("\n*   xxxxxxxxxxxx@xx.edu          *");
    printf("\n*   Lab section = Fri. 11:30     *");
    printf("\n**********************************");
}

/**************************************************************************
     Function: compute_cylinder_surface()
     Input Paramaters: radius and height (both float)
     Output data type: float
     Task: Compute the surface area of a cylinder and return it as output. The surface are of a cylinder is the area of its side plus 2 times area of its base.
****************************************************************************/
float compute_cylinder_surface(float height, float radius) {
    float SA;
    SA = 2 * PI * radius * height + 2 * pi * pow(radius, 2);
}

/**************************************************************************
     Function: compute_sphere_area()
     Input Paramaters: Input parameter: radius (float)
     Output data type: float
     Task: Compute the surface area of a sphere, and return it as output. The surface are of a cylinder is the area of its side plus 2 times area of its base.
****************************************************************************/
void compute_sphere_area(float radius) {
    float SA;
    SA = 4 * PI * pow(radius, 2);
}
/**************************************************************************
     Function: verify_triangle()
     Input Paramaters: 3 float
     Output data type: int (1 or 0)
     Task: Verify if the input numbers from a triangle, if the sum of every 2 numbers is greater than third. In other words, all three conditions must be true.
****************************************************************************/

int verify_triangle(float a, float b, float c) {
    if (a + b > c && b + c > a && a + c > b) {
        return 1
    }
    else {
        return 0
    }
}

/**************************************************************************
     Function: compute_area_triangle ()
     Input Paramaters: 3 float
     Output data type: float
     Task: Compute the area of triangle
****************************************************************************/
float compute_area_triangle(float a, float b, float c) {
    float S;
    float Area;
    if (verify_triangle(a, b, c) == 0)
        printf("The input numbers do not form a triangle");
}
else {
S = (a + b + c) / 2;
Area = sqrt(S * (S - a) * (S - b) * (S - c));
return area;
}

int main() {
    float radius;
    float height;
    float area;
    float S;

    int display_myInfo();

}
```

Can someone help me solve this error?
Thank you.

Comment: I don´t think the error is rooted in your code. It seems like some file is misnamed or something, but I cannot really tell from the distance.

Comment: Apparently the project settings aren't correct. The best thing to do is have a more experienced programmer take a look at what you're doing. But if that's not possible, I'd start a new project, and then copy/paste your code into that project.

Comment: The source code as shown is not compileable. Please provide a [example].